# "webpack-cli": Failed to load 'webpack.config.ts' config, TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts"

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I have a TypeScript project, where I transpile to code to JavaScript using Webpack.

My versions:

```json
    "devDependencies": {
        "@commitlint/cli": "17.0.2",
        "@exlint.io/inflint": "1.2.9",
        "@types/inquirer": "8.2.1",
        "@types/micromatch": "4.0.2",
        "@types/minimist": "1.2.2",
        "@types/webpack-node-externals": "2.5.3",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.58.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.58.0",
        "chalk": "5.2.0",
        "commitizen": "4.2.4",
        "cz-vinyl": "1.3.2",
        "depcheck": "1.4.3",
        "eslint": "8.38.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "8.8.0",
        "eslint-plugin-deprecation": "1.4.1",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "2.27.5",
        "eslint-plugin-node": "11.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "2.0.0",
        "figlet": "1.5.2",
        "husky": "8.0.1",
        "is-ci": "3.0.1",
        "lint-staged": "13.0.1",
        "npm-run-all": "4.1.5",
        "prettier": "2.6.2",
        "rimraf": "3.0.2",
        "ts-loader": "9.4.2",
        "ts-node": "10.9.1",
        "tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin": "4.0.1",
        "typescript": "5.0.4",
        "webpack": "5.78.0",
        "webpack-cli": "5.0.1",
        "webpack-node-externals": "3.0.0",
        "webpack-shell-plugin-next": "2.3.1"
    }
```

I running the following: `webpack -c ./webpack.config.ts` and then I get this error:

```
> webpack -c ./webpack.config.ts

[webpack-cli] Failed to load 'webpack.config.ts' config
[webpack-cli] TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for webpack.config.ts
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:79:11)
    at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:121:38)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:81:20)
    at nextLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:605:26)
    at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:457:22)
    at new ModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:64:26)
    at ESMLoader.#createModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:480:17)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:434:34) {
  code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'
}
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 2.
```

I also configured, in `package.json` file this: `"type": "module"`.

This is my `tsconfig.base.json` file:

```json
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.paths.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2018",
        "module": "ESNext",
        "moduleResolution": "bundler",
        "noEmit": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "allowJs": false,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "incremental": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "allowUnreachableCode": false,
        "allowUnusedLabels": false,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitOverride": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
        "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./@types"]
    }
}
```

And this is my `tsconfig.build.json` file:

```json
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noEmit": false,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "declaration": true
    },
    "include": ["./src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

I won't provide the `webpack.config.ts` file for now, as its content seems to be irrelevant for that issue, because even if I keep the file empty, I got same error.

---

I tried to run the build with:
`node --loader ts-node/esm node_modules/.bin/webpack -c ./webpack.config.ts` But then I got the error:

```
> node --loader ts-node/esm node_modules/.bin/webpack -c ./webpack.config.ts

(node:16287) ExperimentalWarning: Custom ESM Loaders is an experimental feature and might change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
/node_modules/.bin/webpack:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1176:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (/node_modules/.pnpm/ts-node@10.9.1_@types+node@18.11.18_typescript@5.0.4/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1608:43)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:169:29)
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: @qrsngky As far as I know I have installed all the required dependencies for that matter: `ts-node`. You can see I have it installed in `devDependencies`

Comment: I just tried actually using package.json with your devDependencies in and ran `npm i`, and I couldn't reproduce your error (I saw `webpack 5.78.0 compiled successfully in 259 ms`). Maybe something with `node_modules` again. (Delete node_modules and re-install again?).

Comment: @qrsngky Did re-install `node_modules` now, it did not resolve the issue. Is there any file to provide here for the issue?

Comment: You seem to have a global installation of webpack (the version may be different from the one in your current project)? What do you get from `webpack --version`? Do you get a different result if you ran `npx webpack -c ./webpack.config.ts` instead?

Comment: @qrsngky Well, I don't have `webpack` globally installed so there is no proper output to give here for `webpack --version`

Comment: @qrsngky the `webpack -c ./webpack.config.ts` is in package json's scripts key.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part where you have to have `"type": "module"` in package.json ; now I can reproduce the error.

Comment: I checked the js files `node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js` (the function `tryRequireThenImport`) and `node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/utils/dynamic-import-loader.js`, and found that it will basically try to first use `require()`, then if it fails, it tries the ES module `import()` function, which will produce that error message if you try to load a 'ts' file directly. 
So I ended up running `node --loader ts-node/esm node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.config.ts` and changing a few more options.

Comment: But I found that the final output, `dist/foo.bundle.js`, only contains regular js code instead of a module with `export` or `import` (not sure if it's because of the config or for some other reason). That seems to defeat the purpose of `"type": "module"` in the package.json

Comment: @qrsngky Doing `node --loader ts-node/esm node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.config.ts` did not help me. Check my edit in the question for the error message

Comment: @TaiRofe Sorry, I copied from the wrong command, it should be `node --loader ts-node/esm node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js --config webpack.config.ts`

Comment: However, even if that part is fixed, `type: "module"` will enforce that your relative imports have extensions, so it will complain about `import("./foo2")`. If you try `import("./foo2.ts")`, it will make another complaint, saying `An import path can only end with a '.ts' extension when 'allowImportingTsExtensions' is enabled.` (you can silence it with `//@ts-ignore;`, but imagine what happens when you have many imports). I then tried `allowImportingTsExtensions`, then it says it requires "noEmit". If I add "noEmit", then "Error: TypeScript emitted no output for <path to file name>".

Comment: @qrsngky this error is irrelevant here as I use `moduleResolution: "bundler"`. do you?

Comment: Yes, I have that error here with `moduleResolution: "bundler"`. But that may be because of some other settings that are different from yours. Let me know if the command above (that worked for you) causes other problems, or if the compilation results are the same as what you expected.

Comment: `moduleResolution: "bundler"` is supported only in `typescript@5` so this is why you might have this issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253135/discussion-between-qrsngky-and-tal-rofe).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Explanation of how the error occurs:

In `node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js`, inside the method `tryRequireThenImport`, it tries to do `result = require(module)`, but this fails if you have `"type": "module"`; it catches this particular error and tries using `dynamicImportLoader`, which is basically just a wrapper around the ES modules' dynamic `import()` function. However, the `.ts` extension is not recognized by the `import()` from a `.js` file, and it results in the error message as shown in the OP.

#### Workaround:

The following may work depending on your configurations.

```
node --loader ts-node/esm node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js --config webpack.config.ts
```

Comment: A related thread, relevant if you used the workaround, but want to avoid emitting `"require"` in the output: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75998513/webpack-bundling-emits-require-statements-in-the-distribution-file/76123674