# webpack-cli TypeError: Unknown file extension ".ts" for webpack.config.ts

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript, webpack

As many of us, I got the same error message when trying to run my new react project, and any of the solutions I found on internet not worked for me.

The full error message is:

```
[webpack-cli] Failed to load 'webpack.config.ts' config
[webpack-cli] TypeError: Unknown file extension ".ts" for webpack.config.ts
    at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:160:9)
    at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:203:36)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:143:22)
    at async ModuleLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:409:7)
    at async ModuleLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:291:45)
    at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:21) {
  code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "black-stage-info-dashboard",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack serve",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-router": "6.21.2",
    "react-router-dom": "6.21.1",
    "@mui/material": "5.15.4",
    "@mui/icons-material": "5.15.4",
    "@mui/lab": "5.0.0-alpha.160",
    "@mui/styles": "5.15.4",
    "nprogress": "0.2.0",
    "react-helmet-async": "2.0.4",
    "ts-lite-store": "2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/copy-webpack-plugin": "10.1.0",
    "@types/node": "20.10.8",
    "@types/react": "18.2.47",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.18",
    "@types/webpack": "5.28.5",
    "@types/react-router": "5.1.20",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "5.3.3",
    "@types/webpack-dev-server": "4.7.2",
    "@types/webpack-node-externals": "3.0.4",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "12.0.1",
    "css-loader": "6.9.0",
    "style-loader": "3.3.4",
    "ts-loader": "9.5.1",
    "ts-node": "10.9.2",
    "typescript": "5.3.3",
    "webpack": "5.89.0",
    "webpack-cli": "5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "4.15.1",
    "babel-loader": "9.1.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "5.6.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "3.0.0"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.ts

```
import path from "path";
import { Configuration } from "webpack";
import CopyWebpackPlugin from "copy-webpack-plugin";
import nodeExternals from 'webpack-node-externals';

const config: Configuration = {
  mode:
    (process.env.NODE_ENV as "production" | "development" | undefined) ??
    "development",
  entry: "./src/index.tsx",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /.tsx?$/,
        use: [
            {
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                options: { configFile: 'tsconfig.json' },
            },
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
  },
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [{ from: "public" }],
    }),
  ],
  externals: [
        nodeExternals({
            modulesDir: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
            importType: (moduleName: any) => `import ${moduleName}`,
        }),
    ],
};

export default config;
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
                                              /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */
  "compilerOptions": {                                        
    /* Basic Options */
    // "incremental": true,                   /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "ES6",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "esnext",                       /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    "lib": ["ES5", "ES6", "DOM"],             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    "allowJs": false,                         /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    "jsx": "react-jsx",                       /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    // "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    "sourceMap": true,                        /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    "outDir": "dist",                         /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    // "rootDir": "./",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "composite": true,                     /* Enable project compilation */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./",               /* Specify file to store incremental compilation information */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */
    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,           /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */
    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
     "noImplicitReturns": true,               /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */
    // "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,      /* Include 'undefined' in index signature results */
    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "moduleResolution": "node",               /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,     /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,          /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */
    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                      /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                         /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */
    /* Experimental Options */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
    /* Advanced Options */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                     /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "ts-node": {
      "esm": true                             /* Tell ts-node CLI to install the --loader automatically */
    }
}
```

Comment: have you seen this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75988522/webpack-cli-failed-to-load-webpack-config-ts-config-typeerror-err-unknown

Comment: yes, not worked for me